# flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing 'wsgi', an ImportError was raised:

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW9bs.png)
In pycharm, I use flask to make a website. Some functions are outside the website. I need to use pywinauto to operate the PC software to automatically handle some things.
But if I create a custom directory in the root directory of flask, no matter what code I put in this directory, it can't run, and the error prompts are displayed in the title of the question.
And the name of the directory I created and the name of the file in this directory do not affect the appearance of this error.
Is this a pycharm problem, or a flask problem? Or is there something wrong with my python environment configuration?

I just tried it again, as long as I create a new python file in the Flask project directory and run it, it will report the above error. As shown in this figure, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd78J.png), test.py and test1.py, test.py is there before, test1.py is just created, the code of the two files is the same, both `a = 1`, but test.py It can be run, test1.py reports an error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because there is no entry point for the Flask application.

You can set `main.py` as entry point with this line of code: `export FLASK_APP = main.py`. I suspect this environment variable is incorrect, I would try running your entry file directly and seeing if it works, if so your environment variable is incorrect.

Otherwise, try running the file which has entry point `def` (function) which might be situated in `app.py` with:

```
# whereever entry point function, here `app()` is written
# write below code and run that file.
if __name__=='__main__':
    app()
```

The entry point function is supposed to set up and wire the Flask application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  But running app.py is no problem, the website can be opened normally. The file I want to run has nothing to do with the flask project, but is just placed under the flask directory. Does this also require an entry to flask? Is it not allowed to have non-flask project files in the flask directory?

Comment: It might be a PyCharm problem. PyCharm is an IDE not a test editor. Whenever you start a project, a build/run configuration is used to run the project. So in your case, a Flask application file runs fine, but the same configuration to run a normal file expects it to be a Flask application, and so it generates the above error.

Comment: Tip: Click on Edit build configuration (left to the Play button, a drop-down button) and read what it is trying to do when you click Play button.